# BitLocker To Go password strength

Tags: encryption, passwords, disk-encryption, bitlocker

When using BitLocker To Go, given that removable drives are inherently offline and may have to resist such attacks, what are the best practices / recommendations for password strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the password takes the role of a symmetric encryption key. So you can use the [recommendations for symmetric keys](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/) given by various trusted institutions.

For example, if you want to have a password of 128 bits of security, you can generate one of at least 22 alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9). You can use a password manager for this, to ensure you do not introduce some bias in the generation process. (For the math: 128/log2(26×2+10) = 21.5)

Comment: When wanting confidence that a potential password / key is sufficiently strong, will a standard password strength / entropy calculator suffice or will a calculator specifically for symmetric keys be needed?

Comment: The entropy of a password once generated is 0 (look up the definition of entropy, log(1)=0). What you can measure is the method to generate passwords. You can also *estimate* the resistance to guessing attacks, but this is unreliable, and unnecessary if you know how the password was generated.